# Setting a Loader on API Call "POST"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When a user fills in the input fields and submits a **POST** method is run.. I would like to show the user that something is happening. A loader, or spinner, or text just that they do not wait guessing something is happening.

I have a solution to that and it works. My challenge is only displaying the **Loader/Spinner/LoadingText** when the `<input/>` fields are not empty and secondly. I would like the spinner to be false when it gets a response from the **API**.

How can I do that ?

Below I have my solution:

```
const [spinner, setSpinner] = useState(false);

const handleSubmit = async () => {
setSpinner(true);

if (!formRef.current?.reportValidity()) {
  return;
}
// You'll probably want to invalidate this token and create a new one
const token = process.env.React_App_Sandbox_Api;
const data = {
  transactionReference: "string",
  paymentMethod: "CreditCard",
  checkoutOrderUrl: "http://localhost:3000/transaction",
  user: {
    name,
    msisdn: phone,
    email: email,
  },
  payementMethodDetail: {
    RedirectUrl: "http://localhost:3000/transaction",
    PurchaseEventWebhookUrl: "http://www.test.com",
  },

  bundle: cart.map((item) => ({
    ProductCode: `${item.ProductCode}`,
    Amount: item.amount,
    CurrencyCode: item.currencyCode,
    Quantity: item.quantity,
  })),
};
const requestOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
};
try {
  const res = await fetch("https://api.flash-internal.flash-group.com/ecommerceManagement/1.0.0/api/checkout/",
  requestOptions
);
if (!res.ok) {
  // some basic handling to come here
return;
}
  setResponse(await res.json());
  navigate("/payment");
} 
finally {
setSpinner(false);
}

return (
  <>
    <form>
      {/* some input fields logic are here */}
    </form>  
    {spinner && <p>something is loading</p>}
    <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button> 
  </> 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, For handling form data (such as validation), I suggest to use library like react-hook-form. Otherwise you can check input's value if it's empty then return false and setError.
if there is no error, call the API. When response received, set spinner false.

```
if (input empty condition) {
setError('fill input');
return false;
}
setSpinner(true);
try {
 // API call
setSpinner(false);
} catch (error) {
setSpinner(false);
setError(error);
}
```

Comment: I already have that login. You are here repeating what I just posted.

Comment: Change the spinner state on onBlur action of every input's you want.